# Ogre For iPhone

Tags: iphone

Do we need MAC OS for Ogre Iphone SDK? and Is there any other way for developing iphone game on windows i mean free open source SDK?

Answer (score 2):

Since iPhone code is C/C++/Objective-C you can write the code anywhere. To use the SDK, compiler and debugger, a computer running OSX is required. Per the license agreement this must be an Apple built piece of hardware, although I've heard that hackintosh machines work just fine.